# Discord.js error: TypeError: client.users.get is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I used to code bots with a friend back in the day for Discord, and was recently thinking I wanted to wake my bots back up from slumber and use some of the commands for a new one.

I realized all my bots must have worked with an older version of discord.js, which I have now updated. But I'm still getting errors while trying to fix a specific command.

The command in question is to add roles to users.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
// add and remove roles
      
if (msg.includes(prefix + 'SUBSCRIBE')) {
    if (message.isMentioned(client.users.get('BOTSCLIENTID'))) {
        message.channel.send("I cannot subscribe to myself, but if I could I would.")
        return
    }
} else if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'SUBSCRIBE')) {
    let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "subscriber");
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();

    member.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
    message.channel.send("You have successfully subscribed.");
}
```

And this is the error it produces:

`TypeError: client.users.get is not a function`

I have tried looking at a TON of different online tutorials, but all of them seem to be trying to make the bots assign roles to do different things (kick users, etc) or via different methods (specifically reactions).

I know this code previously worked, and I even had three different variations on it.

Any explanation or solutions that folks could provide would be great!

I am curious if the way discord.js works has changed significantly since I last used it to make my previous bots (which worked fine).

Thank you for any help or insight you may have!

Comment: From a glance, the version of Discord.JS you used before was v11 or earlier. The current major version of DJS is v14. You'll need to migrate your code to the latest version: https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin.

Comment: For the error, the v14 equivalent would be `client.users.cache.get()`. https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache